# my cursor change if I'm going out of the window

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor

I've created a second cursor named "viseur" that is visible only on a particular scene.

I've called it in my Engine class like that :

```
        viseur = new Viseur(stage);
                stage.addChild(viseur);
                viseur.visible = false;
```

So it's not visible unless the player goes to the particular scene "room3"

```
var isMap:Boolean = thisBack == "room3";
if (isMap) {
    viseur.visible = true;
```

But, if the player use Alt+Tab during the game in order to go back to the desktop and come back to the game, "visor" is visible ! Even if he's not in room 3 ?

Do you know what could cause this ? 
(to resume : if the cursor leave the game windows and come back, the new cursor "viseur" is visible even so it is no suppose to be)

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this line? `var isMap:Boolean = thisBack == "room3";`

Comment: This line is to define isMap. it's essential.

Comment: The if statement says that when the background is isMap (afk room3),  "viseur" is visible.
 
In any other background , "viseur" is false.